# get url of page who contains my google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i go trying to be clear in my request. 
I want to get the url who contains my google app script, not the url of my GSA.
Example : i have a files code.gs who create a html page (html service). this page (html) is a simply form. 
I deployed this script in my Google site. And i want to get url of the page who contains this script.

I hope to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think it is possible to do it programatically, but you can get it in Publish -> Deploy as web app, and save in the code as a Global Variable or script propertie.